# Add Grand Total To Footer Of Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the below syntax to manipulate the `RowDataBound` and the `RowCreated` methods of a gridview so that each time the employeeid is changed to add a total row.  Very basic for me, which is good.  Well I need to take it a step further now and in the footer add a SUM of all the total rows.

How can I achieve this?  Below is what I am using to add the Totals each time the employeeid is changed:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.Columns[14].Visible = false;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                employeeid = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "employeeid").ToString());
                decimal tmpfield1 = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "field1").ToString());
                decimal tmpfield2 = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "field2").ToString());
                decimal tmpfield3= Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "field3").ToString());
                decimal tmpfield4 = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "field4”).ToString());
                decimal tmpfield5 = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "field5").ToString());
                decimal tmpfield6 = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "field6").ToString());
                qtyfield1 += tmpfield1;
                qtyfield2 += tmpfield2;
                qtyfield3 += tmpfield3
                qtyfield4+= tmpfield4;
                qtyfield5+= tmpfield5;
                qtyfield6 += tmpfield6;
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            bool newRow = false;
            if ((employeeid > 0) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "employeeid") != null))
            {
                if (employeeid != Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "employeeid").ToString()))
                    newRow = true;
            }
            if ((employeeid > 0) && (DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "employeeid") == null))
            {
                newRow = true;
                rowIndex = 0;
            }
            if (newRow)
            {
                wh = “11”;
                GridView GridView1 = (GridView)sender;
                GridViewRow NewTotalRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
                NewTotalRow.Font.Bold = true;
                NewTotalRow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
                NewTotalRow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.Text = "Total";
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                HeaderCell.Text = qtyfield1.ToString();
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                HeaderCell.Text = qtyfield2.ToString();
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                HeaderCell.Text = qtyfield3.ToString();
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                HeaderCell.Text = qtyfield4.ToString();
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                HeaderCell.Text = qtyfield5.ToString();
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                decimal grandtotalfield6
                try { grandtotalfield6 = Convert.ToDecimal(qtyfield6) / Convert.ToDecimal(wh); }
                catch { grandtotalfield6 = 0.00M; }
                HeaderCell.Text = grandtotalfield6.ToString("P", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                HeaderCell = new TableCell();
                HeaderCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                HeaderCell.Text = "";
                HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 4;
                NewTotalRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
                GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + rowIndex, NewTotalRow);
                rowIndex++;
                qtyTotal = 0;
                qtyfield1 = 0;
                qtyfield2 = 0;
                qtyfield3 = 0;
                qtyfield4 = 0;
                qtyfield5 = 0;
                qtyfield6 = 0;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
Upon further thought and analysis, I think I can capture the grand total by doing this, but how would I then turn it around and be able to write this info to the footer?

```
sumf1 += qtyfield1;
sumf2 += qtyfield2;
sumf3 += qtyfield3;
sumf4 += qtyfield4;
sumf5 += qtyfield5;
sumf6 += qtyfield6;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.  In your `RowDataBound` code add in the check to determine if you are looking at a `DataRow` or a `Footer`  How you would do such is like so (of course add in for all of the quantities you want to show, but should be a quick text change, as syntax will remain the same)

This is your C# code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
           //Process like you do in your method
        }
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblSum1 = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalqty");
            lblSum1.Text = Sum1.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Modify your HTML to add in a `footertemplate` and populate like so

```
<FooterTemplate>
  <div style="text-align: right;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblSum1" runat="server" />
  </div>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the option GridView1.Rows.Count ?

```
GridView1.FooterRow.Cells[2].Text = Convert.ToString(GridView1.Rows.Count);
```

If i understand you good he start with x rows "Save that amount in a hidden field"

Then every time a row is added subtract it from the total rows and the result will be the total rows added for that person , then set that value to the footer cell

Comment: wouldn't that just give me a count of rows the grid view is showing?

Comment: dident you ask for the SUM of all the total rows ?

Comment: Yes, I did.  But i was not referencing the total row that the grid contains, I was referencing the total row that is added from my RowCreated event handler

Comment: yes that now shows me how to add the value from my sum variables I created in my edit to the footer and add placement.  Where in my C# does the syntax go?  In the OnRowCreated?